# Five people control an element each and are in a competition

Tags: story-identification, novel

I really wish I could remember the title or author of this book, but try as I might, all I can remember is the general plot and one of the main characters names.

What I remember of it is that it was about 5 people, each that controls an element. They are taken under the law to the capitol for a competition to see which group will be the rulers for the next 20 years or so. I believe there were 2 men and 3 women, although that could be reversed. I recall that one of the men's name was Clarion, he was a nobleman, and a little while into the series he started to go by Rion. I also remember one of the women was a courtesan.

Answer (score 15):

This is probably [Convergence, by Sharon Green](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0380784149):

- There is a 25 years recurring event called "the Blending".
- Five heroes control the five elements during this Blending.
- Clarion is an aristocrat, and is "Air".
- "Spirit" is a courtesan named Jovvi.

Seems to match the whole list.

Comment: I got to this question from a Captain Planet question. They share the same elements!